# Google sheets protect range from author

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to lock a cell or a range (protect from accidental deleting or changing) from an author?
In my work there are a lot of ranges/cells on a google sheets(GS) pages which need strong protection from an accidental delete/edit.

There is a possibility of range or sheet protection in GS. There are two options - lock or warning.
The warning option is good because it works for an owner as well as for users. But practice shows, sometimes this allow user to destroy protected cells.
Second option, locking the cell, creates a strong protection from user actions. But has one big problem - it totally ignores protection from an owner actions. As there are always a lot of pages and selections, sometimes accidentally deletions by an owner are happened and make a lot of trouble.

How to lock cells from an author as well as from user actions?

Currently I've found this way: switch an owner to second account, lock cells and then switch an owner back. Cells remained locked for the main owner. This shows total-lock state is possible. But the way described is not convenient. There are a lot of pages, and ranges to protect, and new arises often. So need is for an easy way to use it constantly.

I've posted this a year from now. And an advice about warning option helps for some time. But now there are much more users, and sheets need lock not warning protection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Show warning when editing this range** option.

Comment: It was a really helpul idea on Jul 24 of 2022. Thanks a lot for it. That time work was more about creating a system, and less about users. But now, on October 25, 2023, there are a lot of users already. And warnings are not enough, as sometimes they still can delete/edit.
So still need a total-lock solution, for users and for an owner.
Removes 'solved' mark,  sorry

Comment: There is no feature in Google Sheets that would completely prevent the _spreadsheet owner_ from editing a range. The **Show warning when editing this range** option remains the simplest way to help avoid inadvertent changes. You may want to transfer spreadsheet ownership to a service account and use regular protections. Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.